# IllegalArgumentException in reflection Code

Tags: java, reflection

In my programm I tried to call a method over reflection with this code:

```
private void invokeMethod(Component sender, MouseEvent event)
{
    try 
    {
        System.out.println(name);
        Method method = frame.getClass().getMethod("onButton1Clicked", Component.class, MouseEvent.class); 
        method.invoke(sender, event);
    } 
    catch (Exception e) 
    { 
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

public void onButton1Clicked(Component sender, MouseEvent e)
{
    System.out.println("Test");
}
```

But if I run this code it comes to this exception:

> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: object is not an instance of declaring class

Any ideas where my mistake is?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the method in question is part of the Frame class, you need to invoke it on an instance of Frame.

A quick look at [the JavaDoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Method.html#invoke) tells you the first argument should be the instance on which the method will be invoked.

Try this:

```
method.invoke(frame, sender, event);
```

Comment: Thank you for this :) Works great now. I will accept the answer in 6 minutes.

Comment: @Cilenco - No problem, glad I could help. Remember that the first step when you have a question about Java code is to read the API documentation... which is all I did to find the answer.